# SVG kendodraggable

Tags: svg, kendo-draggable

Does anyone here know how to make kendodraggable work on SVG?

I tried already but things just dont seem to work as I expected.

```
 $('#image').kendoDraggable({
            hint: function (element) {
               return element.clone();
            },
            dragstart: function (e) {
               $(e.target.parentElement).append(e.target);
            },
            drag: function (e) {
                e.target.setAttribute('x', newXPOS);
                e.target.setAttribute('y', newYPOS);
            },
            dragend: function (e) {
            },
            dragcancel: function (e) {
            }
     });
```

Thanks.

Comment: Most SVG elements don't have x or y attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can use transform attribute in svg and change its position.

```
transform=translate(tx,ty) or matrix(1,0,0,1,tx,ty)
```

where tx,ty are your newXpos and newYpos